# How to center entries in cells of a table

Tags: tables, vertical-spacing

> I would like a way to ensure that the entries in a cell are centered (vertically and horizontally) while also leaving some space between the entry and the border.

I tried creating a table, but I don't like where some of the symbols appear in the table. For example, the floor function symbol is touching its upper border.

In the code for the first table, I did not make any attempt to address the vertical spacing within the cells.
[image]
In the code for the second table, I tried editing the vertical spacing but it's not ideal.
[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\tiny{}}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|cc}
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} 
{\tiny{}$\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor $} &  & {\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,0}$} & {\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,1}$} & 
{\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,2}$} &  & {\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor }$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\tiny{}$\frac{p-1}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor 
+1}}$}}\tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & 
\tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} 
{\tiny{}Column Sum } &  & {\tiny{}$1-\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor }{n}$} 
& {\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p^{2}}\right\rfloor }{n}$} & {\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor - 
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{3}}\right\rfloor }{n}$} & {\tiny{}$\cdots$} & 
{\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor 
}}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor 
+1}}\right\rfloor }{n}$} &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} \cline{7-7} 
\end{tabular}{\tiny\par}
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}

{\tiny{}}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|cc}
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} 
\cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} 
{\tiny{}$\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor $} &  & 
{\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,0}$} & {\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,1}$} & 
{\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,2}$} & 
$\phantom{\frac{p-1} 
{p^{+1}}_{_{a}}}$ & {\tiny{}$p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor 
,\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor _{_{\phantom{a}}}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
& \multicolumn{1} 
{c|}{{\tiny{}$\frac{p-1}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor 
+1}}$}}\tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} 
\cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1} 
{c}{} &  & 
\tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} 
\cline{7-7} 
{\tiny{}Column Sum $\phantom{\Bigg(}$} &  & {\tiny{}$1- 
\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p}\right\rfloor }{n}$} & {\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p}\right\rfloor - 
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor }{n}$} & 
{\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p^{2}}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{3}}\right\rfloor } 
{n}$} & 
{\tiny{}$\cdots$} & {\tiny{}$\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p^{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor 
\mbox{\ensuremath{\phantom{\bigg(}}}- 
^{\mbox{\ensuremath{\phantom{\bigg(}}}}\left\lfloor \frac{n} 
{p^{\left\lfloor 
\log_{p}n\right\rfloor +1}}\right\rfloor } 
{n\mbox{\ensuremath{\phantom{\bigg(}}}}$} &  & 
\tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7} \cline{4-7} \cline{5-7} \cline{6-7} 
\cline{7-7} 
\end{tabular}{\tiny\par}
\par\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in` may be stated more succinctly as `margin=1in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

- As you can see, vertical are aligned baselines of math terms.
- For table is used `tblr` of `tabularray since by it is relative simple to horizontal and vertical centering of cells contents
- removed are all clutter of `\tiny`

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Z}={1,3-7,9}{solid}, vlines,
             colspec = {*{7}{Q[c,m, mode=dmath]}  *{2}{Q[c,mode=dmath]}},
             rowsep  = 5pt
             }
\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor
    &   &   p_{\left\lfloor\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,0}
            &   p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,1}  
                &   p_{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,2}  
                    &   &   p_{\left\lfloor\log_{p}n\right\rfloor ,
                            \left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor }
                            &   & \frac{p-1}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor +1}}
                                    \\
\text{Column Sum}
    &   &   1-\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor }{n}
            &   \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor -
                        \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor}{n}
                &   \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor -
                    \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{3}}\right\rfloor }{n}
                    &   \cdots
                        &   \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\left\lfloor
                            \log_{p}n\right\rfloor}}\right\rfloor -
                            \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{\left\lfloor \log_{p}n\right\rfloor + 1}}
                            \right\rfloor }{n}
                            &   &   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can edit other tables on the same way.

Comment: Great. Do you know how to remove the left and right border of a given cell? My previous method in the table mode doesn't agree with the tblr mode.

Comment: @TheSubstitute, vertical lines are determined by option `vlines` in table preamble. If you not liked it, just remove it from table preamble. What about horizontal lines?

Comment: I would use \multicolumn{1}{c}{} when I use {tabular} so that I can remove left and right vertical bars on cells that I wish.

Comment: Not in my solution. Iz doesn't work. In it you have to say which vertical lines should be drawn,.  Similarly as is done for horisontal lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach to thinking about the typographic problem caused by the upper ends of the vertical bars of `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` touching the horizontal lines created by `\cline` (and `\hline`): Instead of inserting extra code to adjust the positioning of the formulas -- a tedious and lengthy job, to put it mildly -- how about using a better alternative to `\hline` and `\cline`? Specifically, the approach should apply better spacing to the horizontal lines, so that the typographic problem never arises to begin with.

The [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package provides just such a better alternative: the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` macros to replace `\hline`, and the `\cmidrule` macro to replace `\cline`. Note that when using the `booktabs` package, one shouldn't use vertical rules in the table. This is not an accident, but a design choice. Do become used to not using vertical lines in tables -- trust me, they won't be missed.

I would further like to suggest that you load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` directive to create a macro called `\floor`. That way, all instances of `\left\lfloor ... \right\rfloor` may be written much more succinctly as `\floor*{ ... }`. In the following screenshot, I use `\floor` in the first row and `\floor*` in the second row.

[image]

All cell items are centered horizontally because we're using the `c` column type throughout. The cell contents are already centered vertically, on the baseline and math axis. If the layout doesn't look vertically symmetrical, it's because the cell contents are highly asymmetrical.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \midrule and \addlinespace macros
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
\midrule 
%% row 1: use '\floor', i.e., don't autosize the delimiters
\floor{\log_p n}         &  
p_{\floor{\log_p n} , 0} & 
p_{\floor{\log_p n} , 1} & 
p_{\floor{\log_p n} , 2} &  
p_{\floor{\log_p n} , \floor{\log_p n} } &  
\frac{p-1}{p^{\floor{\log_p n} +1}} 
\\
\midrule 
\addlinespace[4mm]
\midrule 
%% Row 2: Use '\floor*', i.e., do apply auto-sizing. 
\text{Column Sum}                 &  
1-\frac{\floor*{\frac{n}{p}} }{n} & 
\frac{\floor*{\frac{n}{p^{\vphantom{2}}}} 
     -\floor*{\frac{n}{p^2}} }{n} & 
\frac{\floor*{\frac{n}{p^2}} 
     -\floor*{\frac{n}{p^3}} }{n} &  
\frac{\floor*{\frac{n}{p^{\floor{\log_p n}   }}}
     -\floor*{\frac{n}{p^{\floor{\log_p n} +1}}} }{n}  
\\
\midrule 
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```